# How to set per user mail quota for postfix using policyd v2?

Tags: postfix, email-server, quota, policyd

I have configured cluebringer 2.0.7 mysql httpd and all services are running well .
But now i want to set per user mail quota for outgoing mails and want to restrict for a fix number of mail.
I have tried to setup a quota for my host > r10.4reseller.org but not working

Quota List

> Policy:- Default Outbound   Name:-Default Outbound  Track:-Sender:user@domain  Period:-60  verdict:-REJECT Data:-    Disabled:- no

Quota Limits

> Type:- MessageCount  Counter Limit:- 1  Disabled:-no

Do I need to do anymore settings for quota ?

Comment: Do you want a fix number of mail per hour, day, week, month?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you followed the instructions mentioned in the documentation: http://wiki.policyd.org/quotas

What you show in your question doesn't even look similar to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also restrict users by enabling accounting module in cluebringer.  which is available in beta version 2.1.x

This question can helps you.

> [Postfix limit number of emails send in a month/Day](https://serverfault.com/questions/591037/postfix-limit-number-of-emails-send-in-a-month-day)